# How can I make zsh's vi mode behave more like bash's vi mode?

Tags: command-line, zsh

I am really liking the general speed of zsh, but two things are annoying the heck out of me.

1. I have to hit wait a moment between hitting escape and hitting slash to get to the history search (if it hit slash too quickly it says `zsh: do you wish to see all 514 possibilities (172 lines)`)
2. After entering insert mode because of hitting `a` or `A`, I can't backspace past the point where I entered insert mode.

I know that 2 is like classic vi, but I like the vim style better.

Comment: If anyone is running into the very annoying issue of double escaping causing you to have to hit `i` twice to get back to insert mode, I would highly recommend [this](http://superuser.com/questions/516474/escape-not-idempotent-in-zshs-vi-emulation) fix!

Comment: There is also a good summary here: https://dougblack.io/words/zsh-vi-mode.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

(1). For some reason, bindkey behaves oddly when it comes to "/": `<esc>` followed quickly by `/` is interpreted as `<esc-/>`. (I observed this behavior the other day; not quite sure what causes it.) I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, and if it's a feature if it can be disabled, but you can work around it fairly easily.

This key combo is probably bound to `_history-complete-older`, which is generating the undesired result – you can use `bindkey -L` to see the if this is the case.

At any rate, if you don't mind sacrificing the *actual* `<esc-/>` (pressed together, as a chord) binding, you can re-bind it to the vi-mode history search command, so that typing `<esc>` followed by `/` does the same thing at any typing speed. =)

Since this will be treated as a chord, it won't have the effect of first entering vi command mode, so we'll have to make sure that happens first. First, you need to define a function; put it somewhere in your `fpath` if you use that, or put it in your .zshrc otherwise:

```
vi-search-fix() {
zle vi-cmd-mode
zle .vi-history-search-backward
}
```

The rest goes in your .zshrc either way:

```
autoload vi-search-fix
zle -N vi-search-fix
bindkey -M viins '\e/' vi-search-fix
```

Should be good to go.

(2). You can fix the backspace key as follows:

```
`bindkey "^?" backward-delete-char`
```

Also, if you want similar behavior for other vi style commands:

```
bindkey "^W" backward-kill-word 
bindkey "^H" backward-delete-char      # Control-h also deletes the previous char
bindkey "^U" backward-kill-line
```

Comment: It was under `^[/` not `\e/`, but those are both valid ways of saying escape.  The change works perfectly.  Now that I am playing with it more completely, it looks like zsh's vi mode sucks in comparison to bash's (or at least is not fully configured by default).  One example of this is the fact that it drops you into insert mode after the searching history.  I have to go back to command mode to hit n to find the next search item.

Comment: Well, I don't know if you have any other examples, but the one you mention is my fault, not zsh's. =) What's happened is I've bound a vi-cmd mode editor command in vi insert mode – the command expects the shell to already by in cmd mode and behaves accordingly. We need to write an editor command which first calls the "enter cmd mode" command, and *then* executes `.vi-history-search-backward`. I'll write it and edit my answer – check back later today.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer. Try it out.

Comment: With regards to (2), when I do `bindkey | grep <searchterm>` for any of the terms, they're all prefixed by `vi-`. Do I need to set up `bindkey` commands that aren't prefixed by `vi-`?

Comment: adam_0, I'm not quite sure I understand the question. Perhaps you could elaborate on what you're trying to do, and how what you're seeing differs from what you expect.

Comment: In the meantime, I'll just point out that the `vi-` commands are editor commands for zsh's vi *mode*, not the actual program vi.

Comment: @marshaul, for each of the `bindkey`options you show here, I have an similar option prefixed by `vi-`, but not any exact matches. I'm wondering if I need both the matches exactly as shown here or if the `vi-` ones do the same thing.

Comment: My friend helped me find the answer... by using `bindkey "^H" backward-delete-char` and `bindkey "^?" backward-delete-char`, zsh will act more like vim (which I use) than vi.

Comment: For XTerm users: if (2) doesn't work for you, you need to Ctrl+Left Click then uncheck `Backarrow Key (BS/DEL)`

Comment: Or rather add `xterm*backarrowKey: false` to `~/.Xresources` and then `xrdb ~/.Xresources` so that setting remains after restarting XTerm

Comment: Thank you. These hacks (and those of wjv below, too) make zsh's vi mode go from nigh-unusable to excellent. I created a superuser account so that I could vote you up. :-)

Comment: I should thank the asker, too. What started with a couple lines yanked from my zshrc ended up a much more complete (and halfway decent) answer, with new hacks I hadn't yet bothered to implement myself. My vi mode is much better thanks to this, too. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot — (2) has plagued me for a long time. Could you please explain precisely how and why does this keybinding solves the issue, and why does this issue occur in the first place? As far as I understand, `^?` (I assume `bindkey` parses this two-character string into ASCII DEL?) is not equivalent to `${terminfo[kbs]}` (and neither to `${terminfo[kdch1]}`), so why does Backspace send a different sequence when you are trying to delete pre-existing text?

Answer (score 14):

I'm only going to address question (1).

Your problem is KEYTIMEOUT.  I quote from zshzle(1):

> When ZLE is reading a command from the terminal, it may read a
>   sequence that is bound to some command and is also a prefix of a
>   longer bound string. In this case ZLE will wait a certain time to see
>   if more characters are typed, and if not (or they don't match any
>   longer string) it will execute the binding. This timeout is defined
>   by the KEYTIMEOUT parameter; its default is 0.4 sec. There is no
>   timeout if the prefix string is not itself bound to a command.

That 0.4s is the delay you're experiencing after hitting ESC. The fix is to set KEYTIMEOUT right down to 0.01s in one of the shell startup files:

```
export KEYTIMEOUT=1
```

Unfortunately this has a knock-on effect:  Other things start going wrong…

Firstly, there is now a problem in vi command mode: Typing ESC causes the cursor to hang, and then whichever character you type next gets swallowed.  This is because ESC is not bound to anything by default in vi command mode, yet there are multi-character widgets that start with ESC (cursor keys!).  So when you hit ESC, ZLE waits for the next character… and then consumes it.

The fix is to bind ESC to *something* in command mode, thus ensuring that the *something* gets passed to ZLE after $KEYTIMEOUT centiseconds. Now we can keep bindings starting with ESC in command mode without these ill effects. I bind ESC to the bell character, which I find to be even less intrusive than self-insert (and my shell is silenced):

```
bindkey -sM vicmd '^[' '^G'
```

> **Update 2017:**
>
> I have since found an even better solution for binding ESC — the `undefined-key` widget.  I’m not sure whether this widget was available in zsh when I originally wrote this answer.
>
> `bindkey -M vicmd '^[' undefined-key`

Next problem:  There are by default some two-key widgets starting in ^X in vi insert mode; these become unusable if $KEYTIMEOUT is set all the way down.  What I do is unbind ^X in vi insert mode (it's self-insert by default); this allows those two-key widgets to continue working.

```
bindkey -rM viins '^X'
```

You lose the binding for self-insert, but you can bind it to something else of course.  (I don't, since I have no use for it.)

The last problem (I've found so far):  There are some remaining default keybindings that we "lose" due to setting $KEYTIMEOUT right down, to wit:  those starting with ESC in vi insert mode which are *not* cursor keys.  I personally rebind them to start with ^X instead:

```
bindkey -M viins '^X,' _history-complete-newer \
                 '^X/' _history-complete-older \
                 '^X`' _bash_complete-word
```

> **Update 2018:**
>
> It turns out the entire section above (after “Update 2017”) is not necessarily required. It’s possible to set the META key to be equivalent to ESC in keyboard mappings using:
>
> `bindkey -mv`
>
> It is therefore possible *not* to unbind ^X, and to access the keybindings that start in ESC by pressing META as a leader instead (ALT or OPT on modern keyboards).
>
> If you have access to the book *From Bash to Z Shell* by Kiddle et al., the equivalence of ESC and META in keybindings is discussed in the Chapter 4 sidebar on pp. 78–79.

Comment: Thank you. These hacks (and those of marshaul above, too) make zsh's vi mode go from nigh-unusable to excellent. I created a superuser account so that I could vote you up. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I find it a little worrying that, after all this time, we still need what is essentially a hack and a workaround to make a core bit of zsh functionality usable!

Answer (score 0):

I opted to rebeind the history completion to remove the conflict. Run the following after `compinit` binds the chord.

```bsh
bindkey -M viins -r "^[/"
bindkey -M viins "^[." _history-complete-newer
```